# Making a sticky side-nav inside of flex-container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have looked around the internet for help with this issue; often even encountering solutions for other problems, but I still cannot achieve what I am looking for.  I want a sticky side-bar that will stay with the main content of my page.  Later, I will add functionality to that sidebar to enable it to link to various parts of the content (like a table of contents).

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container"> .

  <div class="sticky">
    <div> Section Header 1</div>
    <div> Section Header 2 </div>
    <div> Section Header 3 </div>
    <div> Section Header 4 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

As of right now, the flex containers are doing their job nicely (putting the two divs side by side), but the sticky section is not working like a sticky element, because it's inside a flex-box.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have to your flexbox, for such task the css-grid is the better solution

Answer (score 0):

Your height is `.sticky` for the entire page, and for this reason the sticky block does not work. The sticky block needs space to move.

Add `margin-bottom: auto` to `.sticky` (or you can set `align-self: flex-start` to the same class):

```
.sticky { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 

  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```css
.content-container { 
  display: flex; 
}

.sticky { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.main { 
  flex-grow: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container"> .

    <div class="sticky">
        <div> Section Header 1</div>
        <div> Section Header 2 </div>
        <div> Section Header 3 </div>
        <div> Section Header 4 </div>
    </div>

  <div class="main">
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
     <div> Test </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, is your `.sticky` container has nothing to "stick" against, since it's the same height as your `main` div.

What you need to do is add another element **inside** of your `sticky` element. That element will then stick to it's parent (`.sticky`) on scroll.

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex
}

.sticky .inner {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">

  <div class="sticky">
    <div class="inner">
      <div> Section Header 1</div>
      <div> Section Header 2 </div>
      <div> Section Header 3 </div>
      <div> Section Header 4 </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also avoid the wrapping element, by using `align-items: flex-start` on the `.content-container`. This will make the flex elements the height of their content.

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">

  <div class="sticky">
      <div> Section Header 1</div>
      <div> Section Header 2 </div>
      <div> Section Header 3 </div>
      <div> Section Header 4 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
    <div> Test </div>
  </div>
</div>
```